# Android Apk Install not working

Tags: android, build, installation, apk

I have a problem with an app I developing right now.

When I build a signed APK(with V1 & V2) I can only install it on my own phone(Android 5.0.1). Anyone else(friends with different(all higher) Android versions) can't install the app.

Points I have found that might help to find a solution:

- I renamed the app
- when other people want to install the app it says not special permissions required, but actually, the app needs a few. When I install the app it asks correctly.
- 2000x2000 png icon

More Information:

> minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 25

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't mentioned, hence assuming you are saying can't install from playstore ? but what error message exactly they are getting ?

Comment: in android 6+, non-sensitive permission are not listed when installing app only sensitive one are listed and app needs to ask for these permission to be granted at runtime, so this point is not relevant. Please explain what do you mean by"can't install it on higher android version".

Comment: No trying to install it from an .apk file, is there a way to get to Error Message that is produced by the installer? Because onScreen no Error gets display, after clicking install the Installer just closes without any extra information.